# Customising UserRole in ASP.NET identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

Starting from out-or-the-box ASP.NET Identity, I've got

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
}
```

and have made and applied a *migration* that has added this column to the `AspNetUsers` table.

Now I want to maintain a hierarchy of organizations with the facility to have role membership inherit over that hierarchy.

Therefore I want

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public int OrganisationId { get; set; }
    public bool Cascade { get; set; }
}
```

However, this seems not to be possible since `IdentityUserRole` is not one of the type parameters to `IdentityDbContext` and furthermore seems to create all sorts of problems with the `IUserRoleStore`.

Is there a better way to implement this requirement that is more compatible with ASP.NET Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different `IdentityDbContext` classes and you are looking for `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>` which you can use to change generic type parameter to be your custom role class.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
   /// Existing code
}
```

Very same customization can/should be done to `UserStore` and everywhere you are not using built-in indentity types.

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationUserRole, , string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    /// Possible overrides
}
```

In case you just inherit and use your custom classes it should work out of the box without any excessive development.

**Related links:**

[IdentityDbContext.cs on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityDbContext.cs)

[UserStore.cs on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/UserStore.cs)

Comment: However, I'm now unsure that this is the best way to go around it: maybe I should model _who can do what_ separately to _who can see what_ so that my implementation of IdentityFramework stays closer to what MS intended, and because unrolling my organisation heirarchy inside IF looks difficult.